# jquery each() function not working on input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a cart options that has a increment the product option . The option has an text input and plus / minus options

### Markup

```
<td class="cart-item-qty">
    <div class="quantity-mius">-</div>
    <div class="quantity">
        <input type="text" class="cart-main-product-qty" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-plus">+</div>
</td>
```

`there is about 5 to 6 types of input like above`

### And the JavaScript code:

```
var minus = $(".quantity-mius");
var plus = $(".quantity-plus");
var itemValue = $(".cart-main-product-qty");

$(".cart-item-qty").each(function(index) {
    $(this).find(plus).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        increment();
    });
    $(this).find(minus).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        decrement();
    });
});

function increment(){
    newValue = itemValue.val(); 
    newValue++;
    itemValue.val(newValue);
};

function decrement(){
    newValue = itemValue.val();
    newValue--;
    if(newValue < 1){
        itemValue.val(0);
    }else{
        itemValue.val(newValue);
    }
};
```

When i press the plus button the input value increases in all the inputs and when minus then all decreases.

Comment: What actually you want ?

Comment: I want it increase/decrease only on the relevent input field

Comment: A running code snippet would be better to debug

Answer (score 1):

`Onclick`ing on those `icon` simply call the function and find its `sibling` with that class and calculate the value. Try with -

```
$(".quantity-plus").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    increment($(this));
});
$(".quantity-mius").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    decrement($(this));
});

function increment($this){
    itemValue = $this.siblings('.cart-main-product-qty');
    newValue = itemValue.val(); 
    newValue++;
    itemValue.val(newValue);
};

function decrement(){
    itemValue = $this.siblings('.cart-main-product-qty');
    newValue = itemValue.val();
    newValue--;
    if(newValue < 1){
        itemValue.val(0);
    }else{
        itemValue.val(newValue);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this

```
$(".quantity-plus").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    increment();
});
$(".quantity-mius").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    decrement();
});
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

In `increment` and `decrement`, you're selecting all the input elements at once (the selection is happening outside of the `each` call at the top of the script).

You are therefore trying to call `val()` and `val(n)` on the entire collection of inputs, in affect trying to increment and decrement all of them at once, except in reality `val()` (with no arguments) doesn't work like that (it should never be used with a collection on inputs, but instead with only one input at a time).

You should select the input using `find` within the each like you do with the `+` and `-` buttons, and pass the found input to `increment` and `decrement` as parameters to those functions, or you should do the increment or decrements inline in the `each` block itself instead of in separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

### this works : `manage click event` before selecting each `input`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var itemValue = $(".cart-main-product-qty");

$( ".quantity-mius" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $( ".cart-main-product-qty" ).each(function( index, element ) {
        
        console.log('decrement');
        decrement();
    })    
});

$( ".quantity-plus" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  $( ".cart-main-product-qty" ).each(function( index, element ) {
         
         console.log('increment');
        increment();
    })
  });


function increment(){
    newValue = itemValue.val(); 
    newValue++;
    itemValue.val(newValue);
};

function decrement(){
    newValue = itemValue.val();
    newValue--;
    if(newValue < 1){
        itemValue.val(0);
    }else{
        itemValue.val(newValue);
    }


};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to target only the `input` element related to clicked `plus/minus` button so

```js
$(".cart-item-qty .quantity-mius").click(function(index) {
  $(this).closest('td').find('.cart-main-product-qty').val(function(i, val) {
    var value = +val || 0;
    return value > 1 ? value - 1 : 0
  })
});
$(".cart-item-qty .quantity-plus").click(function(index) {
  $(this).closest('td').find('.cart-main-product-qty').val(function(i, val) {
    return +val + 1 || 1;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart-item-qty">
      <div class="quantity-mius">-</div>
      <div class="quantity">
        <input type="text" class="cart-main-product-qty" value="1" />
      </div>
      <div class="quantity-plus">+</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart-item-qty">
      <div class="quantity-mius">-</div>
      <div class="quantity">
        <input type="text" class="cart-main-product-qty" value="1" />
      </div>
      <div class="quantity-plus">+</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart-item-qty">
      <div class="quantity-mius">-</div>
      <div class="quantity">
        <input type="text" class="cart-main-product-qty" value="1" />
      </div>
      <div class="quantity-plus">+</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart-item-qty">
      <div class="quantity-mius">-</div>
      <div class="quantity">
        <input type="text" class="cart-main-product-qty" value="1" />
      </div>
      <div class="quantity-plus">+</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var minus = $(".quantity-mius");
    var plus = $(".quantity-plus");

        $(plus).on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).parent().find("input.cart-main-product-qty").val(parseInt($(this).parent().find("input.cart-main-product-qty").val())+1);
        });
        $(minus).on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent().find("input.cart-main-product-qty").val(parseInt($(this).parent().find("input.cart-main-product-qty").val())-1);
        });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4wuzokyo/)

Answer (score 0):

You said you had more that one of these on the page.  Is that because there are multiple items in the cart?  I added a `data-` attribute to your container element. Just a thought.  It may help differentiate them.

```
<td class="cart-item-qty" data-cartItemId="3">
    <div class="quantity-minus">-</div>
    <div class="quantity">
        <input type="text" class="cart-main-product-qty" value="1" />
    </div>
    <div class="quantity-plus">+</div>
</td>
```

You are casting too wide a net in your `increment` and `decrement` functions.  You need to find `itemValue` that same way you are finding `plus` and `minus` within `$(this)` in your `foreach`.  You need to pass along a single element.

If you check the docs on jQuery, there is a prescribed way to pass variables to the eventhandler that is called by `on`.  [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Try this:

```
var minus = $(".quantity-minus");
var plus = $(".quantity-plus");
var itemValue = $(".cart-main-product-qty");

$(".cart-item-qty").each(function(index) {
    // need to use THIS this in a nested context.
    var that = $(this);

    $(this).find(plus).on('click', { target: that.find(itemValue)  }, increment);
    $(this).find(minus).on('click', { target: that.find(itemValue) }, decrement);  
});

function increment(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var el = event.data.target;

    newValue = el.val(); 
    newValue++;
    el.val(newValue);
};

function decrement(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var el = event.data.target;

    newValue = el.val();
    newValue--;
    if(newValue < 1){
        el.val(0);
    }else{
        el.val(newValue);
    }
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks almost right.
First change this code

```
var minus = ".quantity-mius";
var plus = ".quantity-plus";
var itemValue = ".cart-main-product-qty";
```

as you use find you don't need the object.
Then the html is not complete, I used this code to make it working

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart-item-qty">
        <div class="quantity-mius">-</div>
        <div class="quantity">
            <input type="text" class="cart-main-product-qty" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="quantity-plus">+</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="cart-item-qty">
        <div class="quantity-mius">-</div>
        <div class="quantity">
            <input type="text" class="cart-main-product-qty" value="1" >
        </div>
        <div class="quantity-plus">+</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

While the js is

```
var minus = ".quantity-mius";
var plus = ".quantity-plus";
var itemValue = ".cart-main-product-qty";

$(".cart-item-qty").each(function(index) {
    var outer = $(this)
    $(this).find(plus).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        increment(outer.find(itemValue));
    });
    $(this).find(minus).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        decrement(outer.find(itemValue));
    });
});

function increment(item){
    newValue = item.val();
    newValue++;
    item.val(newValue);
};

function decrement(item){
    newValue = item.val();
    newValue--;
    if(newValue < 1){
        item.val(0);
    }else{
        item.val(newValue);
    }
};
```

Note that I added an argument to the functions increment and decrement because I guess you want to change just the relative input field